# ruby - how to encrypt text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, cryptography

I need to encrypt a string (from a text area) that will also be decrypted later on when it is displayed.

I'm not to concerned about it being majorly secure, but just don’t want to store the data in plain text format.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this easily in Rails?

Answer (score -25, accepted):

If you're not concerned about security you can just base64-encode your string:

```
encoded = Base64::encode(string)
decoded = Base64::decode(encoded)
```

By the way it's also suitable for encoding binary data.

**This isn't really encrypting** as any developer may even guess that its Base64 encoded data.

Comment: Although you mention security a casual scan by a hasty developer could cause them to forget that. Since the question was about encrypting this answer is in fact incorrect

Comment: I feel like @neutrino is being given a bit of a hard time here. The commenters are correct, but he did preface his response with "if you're not concerned with security". I think everyone is just over-reacting to the fact that it was chosen as 'correct', and devs that understand the difference between encoding and encrypting are worried that someone that stumbles upon this thread will use the 'correct' answer. 
I really wish I could edit the answer, and that would solve everyone's problems.

Comment: @jackquack, I would just delete the answer, but I can't since it's accepted :)

Comment: this answer answers the question and helped me solve a similar issue, the question specifies security is not really a concern, maybe the question should be edited and "encrypt" be replaced by  "obfuscate" instead of this answer having negative votes, as if you want encryption security is a concern.

Comment: This is helpful for establishing an email connection beyond a simple ping. +1

Answer (score 20):

There is a RubyGem named [Crypt](http://crypt.rubyforge.org/) that provides a pure Ruby implementation of a number of encryption algorithms.

Comment: The example on their website gave me an error, went for encryptor instead!

Comment: Crypt is not supported on 1.9.1 or bigger – at least at the moment

Answer (score 16):

```
gem install encryptor
```

It wraps the standard Ruby OpenSSL library and allows you to use any of its algorithms.

http://github.com/shuber/encryptor

Answer (score 15):

Is there a ROT13 implementation in Ruby/Rails (there must be...) that's totally insecure except to human readers (and idiot savants) so seems to fit your use case.

*EDIT* - This is a good start for swapping out characters:

```
$_.tr! "A-Za-z", "N-ZA-Mn-za-m";
```

It asks for user input then swaps the characters.

*EDIT* If you're not familiar, ROT13 assigns each letter its natural number. A=1, B=2, etc. Then it adds 13 to each number, effectively spinning it half way around the alphabet. The halfway bit is great, because unlike, say, ROT12, you can just run ROT13 again to decode. One function for both. *OR* you could run ROT12 13 times I guess (12 * 13 = 156. 156/26 = 6.) ROT 13 is better for this though.

Comment: Just don't think that double-ROT13 is more secure like double-RSA might be.